# What is this Mario version of air hockey Shimamura is talking about?

Tags: adachi-and-shimamura

In the second volume of the light novels, in the chapter called *White Christmas*, after playing a round of air hockey, Shimamura says something odd that kind of left me puzzled.

> "Weird... This game doesn't work like I remember..."
> ...
> "I play this game with my sister sometimes. But we have the Mario one, and I think maybe the setup's different."
> [Shimamura] tapped the mallet against her forehead. Evidently, she was well-versed in air hockey, hence that smug chuckle from earlier.

It wasn't really elaborated upon further at any point in this volume. What is she talking about here? A specific video game? If I'm recalling correctly, she and her sister were confirmed to have a Wii. I'm not aware of a Mario air hockey game, but I could easily see it being a mini-game in the *Mario Party* series.

It seems unlikely it would be an actual air hockey table, since Shimamura says it's something she *has*, but I've seen miniature air hockey games, and I even found a Mario one (not sure when it was made , but this one probably doesn't match with the book's timeline of being published in 2013).

[image: Mario air hockey]

Comment: Haven't seen the anime, so I wonder if it adds any clarity

Comment: Just a quick check that the related episode is episode 6, starting around 16:13~. The fansub that I watched mentioned "video game" and certainly doesn't mention "Mario" (possible trademark issue), but it's a bit hard to hear the original Japanese dialog layered with another inner dialog.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Thanks for the timestamp; I checked it myself. So it is most likely refers to a video game in both versions. Shimamura seems drastically different in the two versions. It can't be blamed on translation either, because this moment is actually captured in the colored pictures in the volume, and it shows Shimamura with a much more ditzy expression. Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that it probably isn't the one you have listed; that one was released in 2017, which is much later than the 2013 publishing of the book. This is likely referring to the [New Super Mario Bros. Wii Nokonoko Air Hockey](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%9D%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF-EPOCH-KTEC-cTOTC-ds-1106671-New%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BAWii-%E3%83%8E%E3%82%B3%E3%83%8E%E3%82%B3%E3%82%A8%E3%82%A2%E3%83%9B%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC/dp/B005L9ZZGY) toy, which was released in 2011. This version uses a Koopa shell that can slide on any surface, so you [play without a table](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGRx6zBBoy8).

That reference really is a bit hard to get IMO; maybe it was a hit for the author, who thought the toy would catch on more than it actually did.

Answer (score 0):

Jimmy's answer actually makes a lot of sense, particularly as Shimamura seems puzzled that her past experience with some type of air hockey isn't carrying over to the current match. It would be strange (and kind of dumb, if we're being honest) if she thought playing a video game would help her with actual air hockey.

[image: Shimamura doesn't understand air hockey]

(The translation here would further seem to support that she has a miniature air hockey set. However, the translation I got in the official English release was the quote as seen in my question, mentioning "the Mario one", so that is what I will be focusing on.)

However, considering the expression on her face, and that she taps the mallet against her head, the point may just be that she *is* being dumb. Though the story doesn't justify it much (in my opinion), the summaries on the back and on some of the colored images often describe Shimamura as a "slightly ditzy girl". Additionally, as was pointed out to me in the comments by Aki Tanaka♦, the anime's English subtitles and English dub definitely say "video game". Thus, with this in mind, I decided to look into the video game angle.

Firstly, I think we can confirm we're looking for a Wii game, from these quotes from the book:

> [Little Shimamura] sat on the floor playing a video game, her randoseru backpack lying forgotten in one corner. Specifically, she was playing one of those motion control games where you swing the controller around. Ping-pong, by the looks of it. Onscreen, a little cartoon character jumped for joy; her "opponent" had scored on her while she was distracted.

From *Adachi, Questioning* in volume 1, on page 155

> Once [my sister] confirmed that Adachi was nowhere to be seen, she plopped down in front of the TV in the corner and grabbed a Wii controller.

From *The Isosceles Triangle* in volume 1, on page 158

So the Shimamura sisters are confirmed to have a Wii, and in any event, motion controls would probably be necessary for Shimamura to believe playing the game would make her better at actual air hockey. Going by Wikipedia, *Adachi and Shimamura* was released in Japan on March 10, 2013 (the year matches what is written in the copyright section of my library's copy), so the game in question will have to have come out before then.

### Mario Party

I first looked through the minigames in *Mario Party 8* and *9*.

https://www.mariowiki.com/List_of_Mario_Party_8_minigames

https://www.mariowiki.com/List_of_Mario_Party_9_minigames

However, nothing stuck out to me as looking like air hockey (closest thing was [Shell Soccer](https://www.mariowiki.com/Shell_Soccer)). I had to go back to *Mario Party 2* with [Speed Hockey](https://www.mariowiki.com/Speed_Hockey) and *Mario Party 7*'s [Ice Moves](https://www.mariowiki.com/Ice_Moves) to find something actually resembling air hockey.

### Any Mario Game

So next I checked [*Mario Sports Mix*](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Sports_Mix#Hockey_3), released in 2010 in Japan. This has actual hockey in it. So it's a possibility, but not a likely one, since we'd prefer to find an actual air hockey video game.

There's *[Bowser's Lair Hockey](https://www.mariowiki.com/Bowser%27s_Lair_Hockey)*, which, hey, is actually an air hockey video game! But, problem: it's a flash game used to promote *Mario Party 7*, so it's not a Wii game and is not really something Shimamura could *have*, but is rather something she could have *played* on Nintendo's website.

### Any Wii Game

At this point, I gave up on the whole Mario angle. Anything for the Wii will be sufficient! I wouldn't find it odd at all if someone referred to some random Wii game as a Mario game, particularly if that person is not especially video game savvy (okay, it might be a stretch).

First up is *Okiraku Air Hockey Wii* (JP)/ *Family Glide Air Hockey* which was released in 10/21/2008 in Japan. This game actually fits pretty well. It has motion controls and it is air hockey. Additionally, IGN supposedly said this game is "[a dull, awkwardly controlling air hockey game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Glide_Hockey#cite_note-ign-3)", so there's no way Shimamura would get any actual air hockey XP out of this (though notably, the link on Wikipedia goes to the review for the Table Tennis version of this game, and I can't find this actual quote).

[image: Family Glide Air Hockey]

Next is [*Game Party*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Party), which does have air hockey, but did not seem to have a Japanese release. Which is honestly a shame, because it would be a good contender in spite of it having a side view. See this video, around the 45 minute mark, for some air hockey: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEPvQTR2IBo

The only other thing that seemed almost reasonable was *Wii Play*, released in 2006 in Japan, with its [Laser Hockey](https://nintendo.fandom.com/wiki/Laser_Hockey_(Wii_Play)). I've actually played this one. It's a side view and is honestly more like *Pong* than air hockey. It would be really weird if Shimamura thought these skills would transfer to air hockey. Thus, not a good candidate.

### And What Game is Little Shimamura Playing?

Though not related to the actual question, it should come as no surprise that, after finding those passages about the Shimamuras' Wii again, I also tried to figure out what ping-pong video game Little Shimamura was playing. And I thought I may as well share what I found out.

There are three candidates: *Wii Play*, *Wii Sports Resort*, and *Mario and Sonic at the Olympic Games*, which were all released pre-2013.

After reviewing footage of gameplay, I found some problems with *Wii Play* and *Wii Sports Resort*. In *Wii Play*, you play as disembodied hands, so the characters do not "jump around" after you score a point. The winner does jump and down at the end, however. In *Wii Sports Resort*, you play as cartoon characters (Miis) as in the passage, but they do not jump up and down when they score a point either. I did notice a bystander doing so, however.

In the Dream Tennis mode of *Mario and Sonic at the Olympic Games*, the characters do jump a bit when they score a point, so it technically does fit the description (kind of a weak match, if you ask me, because its more like a couple of hops). As of right now, I haven't actually been able to find a video with someone being scored on, however, so I can't actually say if the *opponent* jumps up and down.